# How to configure my application php sdk (facebook)

Tags: php, sdk, facebook-php-sdk, app-config

I'm trying to create my first login with PHP SDK, apparently I have a bad configuration of the application, I have made a simple code to learn well this SDK but I do not run well, please some help to make this right. Here my sample code:

```
require_once("src/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '{App ID}';

$config['secret'] = '{App Secret}';

$config['fileUpload'] = true;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

echo $facebook->api('/me');

echo $facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: You will get a very good example from facebook php sdk. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk. Example: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: Tahmina Khatoon Hi, I've tried that example but I do not run well, not that I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue. Is it showing any error/exception?

Comment: The window is blank when running the application, and run it another time but could not achieve logout and login with the methods for these actions, told me that there was a configuration error in my application.

Comment: Here's an example that runs well:

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

<a href="<?=$loginUrl?>">Login</a>";

But to make login I get the following error that I can do to fix it.

The provided URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the provided URL is not allowed by the Application configuration. It must match the URL of the Website or the Canvas URL or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the domains of the Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far your comment, I think it is facebook app configuration issue.

Logged in to your facebook ie. https://developers.facebook.com. -> Apps ->Open your app in edit mode. Find "Website with Facebook Login". 
Here put the domain name, from where you are running this app.

```
http://yourdomain
```

For development purpose, you can set

```
http://localhost/
```

in this textbox.

Also set "App Domains" same as above. Now try again. Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: I found the problem. I had to set my "Website with Facebook Login" the same url of the site where my example. Many Thanks Tahmina Khatoon.